# How to find keywords that users are using for searches

Tags: algolia

I want to find ways to understand what are the keywords that users are using for searches so that I can strategize future features for the platform in algolia

Answer (score 0):

Algolia has analytics built-in. You can find them in your Algolia Dashboard, under the "Analytics" tab.

You can have an overview of the analytics in the documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/analytics/analytics-overview/